# Transform and group row data into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to combine different rows into a single row with columns.

Let's take this example table:

```
destinationIP       sourceDataCenter         latency
-------------       ----------------         -------
1.1.1.1             Data Center A            10ms
1.1.1.1             Data Center B            12ms
1.1.1.1             Data Center C            5ms
1.1.1.2             Data Center A            50ms
```

Desired output:

```
destinationIP     Data Center A     Data Center B     Data Center C
-------------     -------------     -------------     -------------     
1.1.1.1           10ms              12ms              5ms
1.1.1.2           50ms
```

Please note that Data centers are not necessarily these three, they can be `N` different data centers that I will not know in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL PIVOT operator?

Comment: I haven't, I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have a query that returns `N` columns. Each (particular) query must return a result set that has a fixed "shape" - that is, the same columns, where "same" is the names and data types. It cannot change the number of columns returned, nor their names and data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a known set of `sourceDataCenter` values, you can just use a simple [`PIVOT` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE
(
  destinationIP    varchar(15), 
  sourceDataCenter varchar(255), 
  latency          varchar(32)
);

INSERT @x VALUES
('1.1.1.1','Data Center A','10ms'),
('1.1.1.1','Data Center B','12ms'),
('1.1.1.1','Data Center C','5ms'),
('1.1.1.2','Data Center A','50ms');

SELECT destinationIP, [Data Center A], [Data Center B], [Data Center C]
FROM @x AS x 
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(latency) FOR sourceDataCenter IN 
  (
    [Data Center A],[Data Center B],[Data Center C]
  )
) AS p
ORDER BY destinationIP;
```

If you don't know the names of the data centers in advance, you need to use dynamic SQL to generate an equivalent query, first by getting the distinct list of values, and then adding those into the two relevant spots in the query:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
  destinationIP    varchar(15), 
  sourceDataCenter varchar(255), 
  latency          varchar(32)
);

INSERT dbo.YourTable VALUES
('1.1.1.1','Data Center A','10ms'),
('1.1.1.1','Data Center B','12ms'),
('1.1.1.1','Data Center C','5ms'),
('1.1.1.2','Data Center A','50ms');

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(nax) = N'', @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @cols = (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(sourceDataCenter)
  FROM dbo.YourTable GROUP BY sourceDataCenter ORDER BY sourceDataCenter
  FOR XML PATH(''), 
  TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)');

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT destinationIP' + @cols + '
 FROM dbo.YourTable AS x 
 PIVOT 
 (
   MAX(latency) FOR sourceDataCenter IN (' + STUFF(@cols,1,1,'') + ')
 ) AS p
 ORDER BY destinationIP;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please note that Data centers are not necessarily these three, they can be N different data centers that I will not know in advance.

Comment: @user3077959 you should state those requirements up front. Updated my answer to accommodate.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much! I'm sorry for not clarifying that up front. Pablo.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   destinationIP
,        max(case when sourceDataCenter = 'Data Center A' then latency end) as A
,        max(case when sourceDataCenter = 'Data Center B' then latency end) as B
,        max(case when sourceDataCenter = 'Data Center C' then latency end) as C
from     YourTable
group by
         destinationIP
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please note that Data centers are not necessarily these three, they can be N different data centers that I will not know in advance.